# Having problems with paging

Tags: categories, pagination

My `category.php` lists articles on the first page, and on the bottom I have a pager.

When I click page 2, the index.php page is loaded and the url looks like this: `http://
www.mysite.com/some-category/page/2`.

Why isn't category.php page loaded when URL has `/page/2/` ?

My permalink structure looks like this: `/%category%/%postname%/`

If it helps to see the code, here it is:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Article List - Category
 *
 * Displays articles from magazine
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Norwegian_Fashion
 * @since Norwegian Fashion 1.0
 */

  get_header(); 

  // Get current page. Is used for pagination.
  $page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

?>
  <div id="mainArea">
    <div id="articleList">
      <ul>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
          <li>
            <div class="photo">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_related_image_scaled('h=180') ?> </a>
            </div>

            <div class="info">
              <span class="date"><?php the_date(); ?></span> | by <span class="byline"><?php the_custom_author(); ?></span>
              <header> <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1></header> 
              <div class="intro"><?php the_intro('num_words=25'); ?></div>
              <div id="post_metadata">  
                <div class="keywords"> <?php the_tags('Keywords: ', ','); ?> </div>
              </div>
              <div class="commentsCount"><?php comments_number('no comments','1 comment','% comments'); ?></div>       
            </div>      
          </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
      </ul>
      <?php  
        if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) 
        { wp_pagenavi(); } ?>
    </div>
  </div>

  <aside>
    <div id="sidebar">
      <ul>  
        <?php //dynamic_sidebar( 'frontpage' ); ?>
      </ul>  
    </div>
  </aside>
  <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: we'd probably need to see the code from the whole file. That url looks right to me for getting you page 2 so I figure something else must be screwing it up. Paste the code into your question please.

Comment: Does the page work correctly if you use one of the provided permalink structures?

Comment: @curtismchale - code added

Comment: Are you using a category base in permalinks? If not, using one would probably solve this.

Comment: @hakre: I have written in my question, my permalink setup.

Comment: You don't need to set the paging, WordPress will deal with this for you, you should only need to redeclare paging values when you change the query object.. (additionally your $page var might also be clashing with a WP variable - name it something else).

Comment: I'm gonna guess that you have some confusion in your category slug. Just tried your site and *http://www.norwegianfashion.no/category/fashion-report/page/5/* works, but *http://www.norwegianfashion.no/fashion-report/page/5/* fails. Check the category base in your permalinks settings, and if necessary, add a slug there.

Comment: Oops, sorry. hakre already posted my suggestion. In any case I think its right. A category base in permalink structure will fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found he answer.

The problem was that my URL looked like this: `www.mysite.com/wp-category/`.
This was wrong.

The right way was this: `www.mysite.com/category/wp-category/`.
Now it works.

I thought that since I was using the following permalink: `/%category%/%postname%/`,  did not need the extra `/category/` in my URL. But now I know.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong.

I guess you use that code to custom display a category.

If that's the case, right before this code:

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

You will need to add query_posts():

```
<?php query_posts('cat={categoryID}&paged=' . $page); ?>
```

Comment: If `category.php` has been loaded as the template file, it means `is_category()` should return `true`, and this implies the search is already limited to the given category.

Comment: As Jan points out, `/some-category/` is a category. The category will always be in the URL.

Comment: since this is the category template, I'm guessing that WP "see's" that `/category-name/` is a category and thus I do not have to figure out what cat ID it is. Henche I should not need to use `query_posts`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is actually an issue with your loop. Try using this one below (with the content setup as you need).

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php // Individual Post Styling ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php // paged navigation - next post, previous post... ?>

    <?php else : ?>

    <h3>Ooops looks like there was an issue. Please <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/contact" title="Contact Us">get in touch</a> with us and we'll get the problem fixed.</h3>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This did not help. The reson is that when I click 2 in page list, Wordpress does not recognize that it is a category page, tehrefore it loads the frontpage, but with some weird styling. You can see it in action here: http://www.norwegianfashion.no/fashion-report/

Comment: As hakre suggested, add a category base to your permalink structure.